# Group rows which overlap with month (month on month) Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data in the following format

```
id                  current_period_start    current_period_end
sub_EoJifk08hBL5Tz  2019-07-02 07:30:28 UTC 2019-08-02 07:30:28 UTC
sub_EoJifk08hBL5Tz  2019-07-02 07:30:28 UTC 2019-08-02 07:30:28 UTC
sub_EoJifk08hBL5Tz  2019-07-02 07:30:28 UTC 2019-08-02 07:30:28 UTC
sub_EoJifk08hBL5Tz  2019-07-02 07:30:28 UTC 2019-08-02 07:30:28 UTC
sub_EoJifk08hBL5Tz  2019-07-02 07:30:28 UTC 2019-08-02 07:30:28 UTC
...
```

- Note there are duplicate rows for each unique `id`

I would like to count the number of UNIQUE `id`s for each month where the following condition is met:

```
WHERE current_period_end > start_month and current_period_start < end_month
```

`start_month` and `end_month` are every month going back to the earliest `current_period_start`.

The desired output would be as so

```
month                           count  
2018-04-27 13:04:19.157149 UTC  20
2018-05-27 13:04:19.157149 UTC  33
2018-06-26 13:04:19.157149 UTC  61
2018-07-26 13:04:19.157149 UTC  93
2018-08-25 13:04:19.157149 UTC  128
```

---

Current attempt

1. Generates last 50 months.
2. Matches IDs which match condition.
3. Count IDs

While this does seem to generate the desired output, generating timestamps in this way does not feel great.

```
WITH grouped_by_unique_id AS (
    WITH all_timestamps AS (
        --  Generate timestamps for last 50 30 day periods (hack)
        SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -30*num day) AS t FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 50)) AS num
    ) 
    SELECT t, id
    FROM all_timestamps, my_data
    WHERE   current_period_end > TIMESTAMP_SUB(t, INTERVAL 24*30 HOUR) 
        AND current_period_start < t
    GROUP BY t, id
    ORDER BY t, id
)
SELECT t AS month, count(*) AS count
FROM grouped_by_unique_id
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY t desc;
```

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY? And your result set doesn't match your data set. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: updated to match query output format. Primary key is not relevant here.

Comment: Then neither is my answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `generate_timestamp_array()` and generally simplify your query:

```
select t AS month, count(distinct d.id) AS paying_customers
from unnest(generate_timestamp_array( date_timestamp(current_timestamp, interval -30*2 day),
                                current_timestamp,
                                interval 30 day
                               )
           ) ts left join
     my_data d
     on d.current_period_end > timestamp(ts, interval 30 day) and
        d.current_period_start < t
group by ts
order by ts;
```

Using date/timestamp functions in BigQuery, you can use more precise measurements, such as calendar months.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem of overlapping event windows. Try this approach (uses BQ's `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` function:

```
with intervals as (
  select 
     month as start_month, 
     coalesce(lead(month) over (order by month), month) as end_month 
  from (
      select 
         generate_date_array(
           date(extract(year from min_date), extract(month from min_date), 1),
           date(extract(year from max_date)+1, extract(month from max_date), 1),
           interval 1 month
         ) as months  
      from (
         select 
            min(date(current_period_start)) min_date, 
            max(date(current_period_end)) max_date 
         from `dataset.table`
      )
  ), unnest(months) as month
)

select 
   start_month, 
   end_month, 
   count(distinct id) as count 
from (
   select 
      d.current_period_start, 
      d.current_period_end, 
      d.id, 
      i.start_month, 
      i.end_month
   from intervals i
   left join data d on 1=1
   where d.current_period_end > i.start_month and d.current_period_start < i.end_month
)
group by 1,2
order by 1,2
```